# QTableView search and highlight items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I search and highlight an item in a QtableView. I did a basic search and highlight, but when I clear text highlight still there and move to another item. 
the problem is when clear the text, it doesn't remove highlights. Can you please show me how to fix this.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


Mylist   = ['Apple','Orange','lemon']

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, mylist):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        # mylist
        self.mylist = mylist

        # layout
        Layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Model and listview
        self.viewL = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        # Add items
        for Name in self.mylist:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(Name)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.model.appendRow(item)

        # set the model
        self.viewL.setModel(self.model)

        # 
        search = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        search.textChanged.connect(self.myfilter)
        #
        Layout.addWidget(search)
        Layout.addWidget(self.viewL)

        self.show()

    def myfilter(self, text, column=0):

        start = self.model.index(0, column)
        matches = self.model.match(
            start, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,
            text, 1, QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
        if matches:
            index = matches[0]
            # index.row(), index.column()
            self.viewL.selectionModel().select(
                index, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select)



app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=Window(mylist=Mylist)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


Mylist   = ['Apple','Orange','lemon']

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, mylist):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        # mylist
        self.mylist = mylist

        # layout
        Layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Model and listview
        self.viewL = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        # Add items
        for Name in self.mylist:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(Name)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.model.appendRow(item)

        # set the model
        self.viewL.setModel(self.model)

        # 
        search = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        search.textChanged.connect(self.myfilter)
        #
        Layout.addWidget(search)
        Layout.addWidget(self.viewL)

        self.show()

    def myfilter(self, text, column=0):
        self.viewL.clearSelection()                                     # +++
        if text:                                                        # +++
            start = self.model.index(0, column)
            matches = self.model.match(
                start, 
                QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole,
                text, 
                hits=1, 
                flags=QtCore.Qt.MatchContains
            )
            if matches:
                index = matches[0]
                # index.row(), index.column()
                self.viewL.selectionModel().select(
                    index, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select)


app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=Window(mylist=Mylist)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, That is what I am seeking. Thanks:)